# Move objects with certain properties to front of array

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array called `dogs`. I want to sort my array of dogs where dogs with a property of `breed` being `Shiba` will be at the beginning, all other breeds will be in the middle and dogs without a breed will be at the end of the array.

```
let dogs = [
  {id: 0, breed: 'Pug'},
  {id: 1, breed: 'Shiba'},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3, breed: 'Shar Pei'},
]
```

The result should be something like:

```
[
  {id: 1, breed: 'Shiba'},
  {id: 0, breed: 'Pug'},
  {id: 3, breed: 'Shar Pei'},
  {id: 2},
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over array and create individual temp array based on filtered data, and combine them to return final array.

```js
let dogs = [
  {id: 0, breed: 'Pug'},
  {id: 1, breed: 'Shiba'},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3, breed: 'Shar Pei'},
];

const arrangeList = (list) => {
  let finalList = [];
  const breedList = [];
  const nonBreedList = [];
  for (obj of list) {
    if (obj.breed === "Shiba") {
      finalList.push(obj);
    } else if (obj.breed?.length > 0){
      breedList.push(obj);
    } else {
      nonBreedList.push(obj);
    }
  }
  return [...finalList, ...breedList, ...nonBreedList];
}

console.log(arrangeList(dogs));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go;

```js
    let dogs = [
      {id: 0, breed: 'Pug'},
      {id: 1, breed: 'Shiba'},
      {id: 2},
      {id: 3, breed: 'Shar Pei'},
    ]
    
    const sorting = (arr) => {
      arr.map(obj => {
        if (obj.breed == 'Shiba') {
          dogs.splice(dogs.indexOf(obj), 1)
          dogs.unshift(obj)
        }
    
        if (!obj.breed) {
          dogs.splice(dogs.indexOf(obj), 1)
          dogs.push(obj)
        }
      })
      return arr;
    }
    
    console.log(sorting(dogs))
```